# How to use assert and retract in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

In SWI-Prolog, if I use assert and retract at the prompt, I get

```
?- assert(at(1)).
true.

?- retract(at(1)).
true.
```

However, if I put these statements into a program file called "test" as

```
assert(at(1)).

retract(at(1)).
```

and run SWI-Prolog as

```
> swipl
?- [test].
```

I get

```
ERROR: /....../test:2:
        No permission to modify static procedure `retract/1'

true.
```

What does this mean and how should I deal with it?

Comment: See "dynamic" in the example at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dynamic/1

Comment: That example works if you manually type each instruction into SWI-Prolog at the command prompt, but it doesn't work if you put the instructions into a file and run the file as a program.  It appears the SWI-Prolog doesn't support this.  Would you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Put statements *within* a predicate, e.g.:

```
:- dynamic at/1.

test_assert :-
    assert(at(1)).

test_retract :-
    retract(at(1)).
```

Load the program, and then run:

```
?- test_assert.
true.

?- at(X).
X = 1.

?- test_retract.
true.

?- at(X).
false.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to put the assert/retract statements in the head of the rule, not the body, like in "assert(at(1)) :- something".  I'm getting the impression that this isn't allowed in a program file.   Is this correct?

Comment: Hello again,

I tried another test with a program file called "test4" and containing the
single line

retract(at(1)) :- true.

Loading this in SWI-Prolog gives:

?- [test4].
ERROR: /......../test4:1:
        No permission to modify static procedure `retract/1'
true.

So I guess you just can't do this.  It seems that the Prolog semantics
doesn't support it.

Comment: Thanks to brebs and TessellatingHeckler.  I think that you have answer my question.

Comment: Cannot assert in the rule head. What exactly is wrong with putting it in the *body*? What are you *really* trying to do? Perhaps you want to use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_expansion/2

Comment: I'm looking into the possibility of building a STRIPS-like automated planner in Prolog.  STRIPS has rules of the form "IF Certain preconditions are met, then RETACT certain statements from the knowledge base and ADD certain other statements to the knowledge base".  I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Prolog where the knowledge base is the actual Prolog program itself (not a list of items held to be true), or whether this is even possible.  It seems that Prolog doesn't support such actions directly on the program itself.   But I am trying to understand that page you referenced.

Comment: Asserting and retracting are actions, and actions are done in the rule body. To add a rule at compilation/load time, just add the raw rule to the source file, no need to assert the rule.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I obviously need to spend more time reading the reference manual.  Your pointers are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt and source code files are different environments with slightly different behaviours. It's like the difference between calling Python `len(x)` in the repl and writing `function len(x):` in Python source code - you would be overriding the builtin `len()` with your own one. Python lets you do that, SWI Prolog also does but not easily.

When you type them at the prompt, you call the existing predicate `assert/1` and actually do insert the fact `at(1).` into the database. When you type `retract/1` you actually do retract the fact `at(1)` from the database.

In a fresh prompt, try `?- listing(at).` and get an error, then `?- assert(at(1)).` then do the listing again and see the fact, then retract it and try the listing and see only the remains of the dynamic declaration and the fact is gone.

When you put them in a source code file, you would be trying to override the existing builtin predicates with your new ones. Your new ones say "assert/1 is a predicate which succeeds when its arugment unifies with `at(1)`" and "retract/1 is a predicate which succeeds when its arugment unifies with `at(1)`".

That is, they don't *do* any asserting or retracting or database changes.

In your test file, put this:

```
:- redefine_system_predicate(assert(_)).
:- redefine_system_predicate(retract(_)).

assert(at(1)) :- true.
retract(at(1)) :- true.
```

Then save and consult it:

```
?- [testing].
true.

?- listing(at).     % <-- your code ran, but did not insert `at(1)`.

ERROR: procedure `at' does not exist (DWIM could not correct goal)
^  Exception: (13) setup_call_catcher_cleanup(system:true, prolog_listing:listing_(user:at, []), _19450, prolog_listing:close_sources) ? abort

% Execution Aborted
?- assert(P).        % <-- it's now behaving 
P = at(1).           % <-- like any other predicate.
```